# How can I make Google Chrome's minimize, restore and close buttons match those of other programs?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

I like the way Google Chrome puts the tabs above the address bar, but I don't like the way the minimize, restore, close buttons are a different shape to every other program's. It means that if I sit the mouse in the top corner and minimize everything, I find that I've restored Chrome, not minimized it.

Is there any way to get these buttons to a normal shape and size?

[image: Google Chrome above; Firefox below]

That's Firefox in front, looking normal, like every other program, and Chrome above and behind, with the buttons at an off-standard position and size.

Comment: I guess you use something else than Windows. Because here, (Windows 7) its perfectly the same size, position, shape, etc etc.

Comment: Chrome on OS X looks fine, too.

Comment: Also, you probably mean maximized? Restore is the opposite action from minimizing.

Comment: I'll make a guess that it's Ubuntu(Linux) or some OS without standards. (Don't take it as an offense, it's unique and good in some way. But got some backdraft. Of course, only if the app uses client-side decoration.. see Chrome.) @TRiG Of course, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Article 1: http://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2010/05/technical-limitations-of-client-side-decorations/ | Article 2: http://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2010/05/follow-up-on-client-side-decorations/

Comment: @Shiki, Windows XP. A bunch of programs open. All fully maximised. All have their minimise buttons in the same place, except Chrome, which has much larger buttons, so the restore button is in that spot.

Comment: The Chrome folks probably hard-coded the Vista/7 window style, which would look out of place for Windows XP.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu at home, XP in work, but I don't have Chrome at home yet, so I don't know how it behaves there.

Comment: @Arjan, Image added.

Comment: @TRiG, is that a combined image, or does Chrome actually show you *two* sets of buttons?

Comment: @Arjan looks combined for the contrast between Chrome's window style and a regular window. Seems I was right earlier :-)

Comment: @Arjan: Chrome above, Firefox below. (That's shown in the `alt` text, but I should probably put it into the question text too.)

Comment: @Daniel, Correct!

Comment: @TRiG, in many browsers, `alt` is only visible when no image is shown. For a tooltip, you could have used `title` instead, like `[1]: http://i.imgur.com/xPOaE.png "Google Chrome above; Firefox below"` in your current post, or `![Alt text](http://i.imgur.com/xPOaE.png "Google Chrome above; Firefox below")` in an alternative syntax.

Comment: Question closed [on behalf of the OP](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6907347#6907347) (again, after the community has reopened it).

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using a custom theme in Google Chrome. This, I think, will alter the appearance of the entire Chrome window. If you use the default theme, all UI elements will be the native, Windows, ones. At least this is how my Google Chrome 11 works on Windows 7.

Without a custom theme:

[image: Default theme]

With a custom theme:

[image: Custom theme]

Answer (score 1):

In Linux Chromium I have the option to "Use system title bar and borders" under Wrench->Settings. As is stated, it puts a system title bar above the tabs and has the system shrink/expand/close buttons. I'm not sure if windows chrome has the same option, but if it does it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: That might work, but I've moved to Vista in work now, so this question is moot. Thanks anyway.