# How to get Windows's default minimize, restore and close buttons in Chrome?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, gui

How can Chrome be configured to respect the default behavior for Windows XP forms in Classic mode? Specifically, I'm asking about the minimize, restore and close icons in the upper right-hand corner of a window.

This question has been asked before ([How can I make Google Chrome's minimize, restore and close buttons match those of other programs?](https://superuser.com/q/224417)), but it got closed after the OP upgraded his operating system. As he did before, I'm running Windows XP Service Pack 3 (up-to-date), and I'm still facing this issue.

I guess I'll edit this question, since apparently this is rocket science.  The answer that everyone here is leaping to states "In **Linux Chromium** I have the option to "Use system title bar and borders" under Wrench->Settings. As is stated, it puts a system title bar above the tabs and has the system shrink/expand/close buttons. I'm not sure if windows chrome has the same option, but if it does it may be what you are looking for."

Well, guess what, Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m running under Windows XP doesn't have that option.  Can someone actually *read* these questions before closing it as a dupe?

Comment: I read all of the comments there and here. 1) You are right. That other question is related but doesn't provide an answer for you --- 2) This question needs a major clean up from unrelated comments

Comment: A couple of points to the OP (Chris). 1) Even if the other question doesn't have an accepted answer, that doesn't mean this one isn't a duplicate. It is, and should remain closed as such. Feel free to vote to have the other question reopened. Earning some reputation here on SuperUser will also enable you to upvote it and offer a bounty. 2) Your attitude isn't really conducive to getting your point across. While I can understand you may be frustrated, some of your comments are borderline offensive. If you feel you've been misunderstood, try to explain your position calmly. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the other question has more than one answer. [The other one](http://superuser.com/a/280525/108226) is definitely about Windows, not Linux. Have you checked that out?

Comment: Incredible as it seems, I have actually read the other answer everyone here loves.  Amazingly enough, it does not answer my problem as I am not using themes.  Congrats on closing unresolved questions as duplicates - that is incredibly useful & helpful.  Have I been misunderstood?  I thought my question was pretty clear the first time I asked it.

Comment: We're not closing unresolved questions as duplicates, we're closing duplicate questions as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question will be closed, heres an answer:

Most likely, Chrome was written on a modern version of the .NET Framework which uses the "current" version of the Windows Forms Application.  The current version of Windows Forms Application uses the modern minimize/maximize/restore/close buttons.

This isnt a case of Chrome not respecting MSs standard UI behavior.  They are strictly adhering to it.

Can it be changed?  Im sure its possible, but it would be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: I do *not* find your comment to be helpful.  Windows XP Service Pack 3 is still supported by Microsoft.  Why would the question be closed???